# Iterate over array with hash and filter hash

Tags: javascript, loops

I have an array with hashes inside it:

```
var variable = [];
var a = [
  { "type": "type1", "a": "a" }, 
  { "type": "type2", "a": "b"}, 
  { "type": "type1", "a": "c"},
  { "type": "type1", "a": "d"},
  { "type": "type2", "a": "e"},
]
```

How am I able to iterate over the arrays and hashes and filter them based on the one that has value `"type1"` for `"type"` key and push it to a variable so I get:

```
var variable = [];
var a = [
  { "type": "type1", "a": "a" },  
  { "type": "type1", "a": "c"},
  { "type": "type1", "a": "d"},
]
```

I have tried with the code below, which does the filter correctly, but the output is wrong:

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (var key in a[i]) {
        if (a[i]["type"] == "type1"){
          variable.push({
            "type": a[i][key]
          })
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{type: "type1"}
{type: "a"}
{type: "type1"}
{type: "c"}
{type: "type1"}
{type: "d"}
```

Comment: look at Array.filter() in javascript.

Comment: In JavaScript they're called objects, not hashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array.filter method should do the trick.

```
var filtered_array = a.filter(function(e){
    return (e.type === 'type1')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close, you're just pushing the wrong thing onto the result. You can just push `a[i]` rather than making a new object.

You also don't need the nested loop. That's repeating the push for each property in the object.

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i].type == "type1"){
        variable.push(a[i])
    }
}
```